# Clojure - why do some namespace names just not work?

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I've had a problem, now it's gone, I know what fixed it but I have no idea why. I'm pretty new to clojure, but it seems to me that some namespace names will just not work, and I don't mean obvious ones that are already taken by another symbol.

I have a rather simple project to implement a scheduler, and it has three namespaces: schedule.core, schedule.jdate, and schedule.validation.

The validation namespace worked, but for the jdate namespace I always received errors like this:

> CompilerException java.lang.Exception: No namespace: schedule.jdate,
>   compiling:(schedule/core.clj:1:1)

The errors varied slightly, depending on the way I was currently trying to solve the issue, but basically always meant the same: There was no namespace with that name, in one instance the error even said that there was no jdate__init (which I could believe) AND no jdate.clj, although the file was right there in the folder.

My namespace declarations and inclusions looked like this:

```
src/schedule/core.clj: 
(ns schedule.core
  (:gen-class)
  (:require schedule.jdate)
  (:refer schedule.jdate)
  (:require schedule.validation)
  (:refer schedule.validation))

src/schedule/jdate.clj:
(ns schedule.jdate
  (:gen-class)
  (:import java.util.Date)
  (:import java.util.Calendar))

src/schedule/validation.clj: 
(ns schedule.validation
  (:gen-class))
```

As I said, the validation namespace worked without trouble.
Eventually I ran out of ideas and started to try things that couldn't possibly have any relation, among other things I renamed the jdate namespace to scheduledate. There was no change in the behavior.

Some more time later, I got to the "I'm not even trying anymore" stage, in which I renamed the jdate namespace to "murks" (a swiss word conveying the meaning of "I need a larger hammer for this to work") and... it worked. 
I thought there must be something somewhere else in the code I changed inadvertantly that suddenly made it work. So I changed the name back to jdate. It stopped working immediately.

In the end, I'm somewhat confused. Could anybody here tell me a) why the first two names didn't work and the third one did, and b) by extension what names are save to use for namespaces, because I'm not looking forward to the feeling of playing minesweeper when naming them in the future.

EDIT: It seems that the problem stemmed from multiple conspiring sources. For one, the structure of my code required a two-way dependency of two namespaces. Since I was not very familiar with how Clojure works, I assumed a c-style include hierarchy, where files included later in the same tree had all the includes up to that point at their disposal. I am somewhat surprised at the nature of the received errors, but then again, I should know by now that Clojure error messages are almost indecipherable and tend to be highly misleading. 
The inconsistent behavior seems to have originated from me frantically trying to reload different namespaces without closing the REPL in-between... i.e. the results of the REPL-operations did not always reflect the state of the code.

Oh well, that was a rather tedious lesson in "Clojure really hates circular includes", but I think it's one I've learned now.

Comment: Since you made clear that you have the namespaces in different files, it's a "works for me". Any more differences between the actual and the example code you provided?

Comment: not in the declarations, no... I guess I should check if it works without any other code in the files.

Comment: Hrm, yes, it works... this is getting weirder and weirder.